# Heat capacity of a crystalline solid at low temperatures

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

I have a system described by

$u(s,v)=A*Exp(B(v-v_0)^2)*s^{4/3}*Exp(\frac{s}{3R})$. It's supposed to follow that the heat capacity $c_v$ is proportional to $T^3$ for $T\to0$

I don't really understand how this can be shown with the information given. Trying to calculate $\left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial T} \right)_v$ seemingly doesn't lead me anywhere.

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Is $u$ the internal energy, $s$ the entropy, and $v$ the volume (or is $v$ the specific volume)?

Comment: Use $T=\partial_su$ for temperature. Express $u$ as a function of $T,v$ and use $c_v=\partial_T u$

Comment: @march Yes, sorry. They're the mentioned quantities per mole, but I don't think it matters here

Comment: @Ipz Wouldn't this expression still have $s$? Wouldn't it be still necessary to find something like $s(T)$?

Comment: I meant that you need to start by inverting the expression $T = \partial_s u$. This gives you $s$ as a function of $T,v$. Btw it's "LPZ" for the tag, otherwise I won't get notified ;)

Comment: @lpz Right, hope this works. Anyway, how can I invert it? An expression containing something like $x^k*e^x$ which I get after differentiating can't be inverted using elementary functions.

Comment: Yes but you want the leading order asymptotic as $T\to0$, ie $s\to0$. Essentially, $u\sim s^{4/3}$ so $T\sim s^{1/3}$ giving $u\sim T^4$ and $c_v \sim T^3$. While it is not mathematically valid to differentiate an asymptotic expansion, the result turns out to be true in this case.

Comment: I see, that was easier than I thought. Well, thanks again for the help.